# Why don't my files appear when I write to them in this multiprocessor code in Python

Tags: python-3.x, filewriter

Here is my code in python. I'm trying to create 2 files, each with 5000 lines each.

```
import multiprocessing
import itertools
import os


# Define a generator function to yield lines of text
def generate_lines():
    # Replace this with your logic to generate lines of text
    for i in range(10000):
        yield f"Line {i + 1}"


# Function to write lines to a file
def write_lines(filename, lines):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        try:
            for line in lines:
                file.write(line + '\n')
        except IOError as e:
            errno, strerror = e.args
            print(f"I/O error({errno}): {strerror}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Get the absolute path of the script's directory
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print('script_dir: ', script_dir)
    # Create a pool of processes`
    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
        # Use itertools.islice to split the generator into chunks of 5000 lines each
        total_lines = 10000
        chunk_size = 5000
        lines_generator = generate_lines(total_lines)
        for i in range(0, total_lines // chunk_size):
            chunk = itertools.islice(lines_generator, i * chunk_size, (i + 1) * chunk_size)
            file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, f'file-{i}.txt')
            pool.apply_async(write_lines, (file_path, chunk))

        # Wait for all processes to complete
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    print("Writing completed successfully.")
```

Why doesn't these files appear in the working directory? conceptually, what is going on? Are the files getting swallowed by the processes and not appear in the main process? How large are these processes in terms of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is an error (which I think may be a typo) when calling `generate_lines`, you call it with an argument:

```
lines_generator = generate_lines(total_lines)
```

but the function does not define any:

```
def lines_generator():
```

Correcting this, there is one error that remains in the shadows: **generators cannot be pickled**.

If you call the **get** method of the `AsyncResult` objects you should see an exception:

```
res = pool.apply_async(write_lines, (file_path, chunk))
res.get()
```

I think the closest thing to using a generator that can be pickled is an iterator, for example:

```
import multiprocessing
import itertools
import os

class LinesIter:
    def __init__(self, lines):
        self._i = 0
        self._lines = lines
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self._i == self._lines:
            raise StopIteration
        self._i += 1
        return f"Line {self._i}"


# Function to write lines to a file
def write_lines(filename, lines):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        try:
            for line in lines:
                file.write(line + '\n')
        except IOError as e:
            errno, strerror = e.args
            print(f"I/O error({errno}): {strerror}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Get the absolute path of the script's directory
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print('script_dir: ', script_dir)
    # Create a pool of processes`
    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
        total_lines = 10000
        chunk_size = 5000
        lines_iter = LinesIter(total_lines)
        for i in range(0, total_lines // chunk_size):
            chunk = itertools.islice(lines_iter, i * chunk_size, (i + 1) * chunk_size)
            file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, f'file-{i}.txt')
            pool.apply_async(write_lines, (file_path, chunk))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        
    print("Writing completed successfully.")
```

Comment: What is getting pickled here and why? Pickling is the serialization of python objects right?

Comment: Roughly speaking, since processes do not share memory space, Python uses Pickle serialization to handle the transfer of objects back and forth between processes. CPython does not support the serialization of generators (although PyPy and Stackless Python do), so it is not possible to transfer the generator to the child process.

Comment: The generator needs to be transferred (serialized) to the child process because `islice` (`chunk` object) needs a reference to it.

Comment: islice needs a reference to "it". What is it? Where can I read more about this?

Comment: why do generators and iterators need to be pickled when sent to a child process but built in functions like islice do not?

Comment: In general, multiprocessing can only transfer Python objects to worker processes that [can be pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). This is the way multiprocessing is implemented, to pass objects and **their state** to child processes, multiprocessing uses pickle to serialize them.  Islice returns an iterator and is therefore *picklable*, but generators are not: https://peadrop.com/blog/2009/12/29/why-you-cannot-pickle-generators/